# Is there a way to get and save an angle of a turtle for later?

Tags: python, turtle-graphics, angle, python-turtle

I'm making a program where the user can click on the screen 3 times and it makes a triangle. It will then find the middle points of those 3 lines. Next, I want it to draw 3 lines perpendicular to each of the lines that make up the triangle (through the middle points).

I'm stuck at drawing the perpendicular lines. I wanted to try to save (like you save a position or coordinates) the angles that the turtle `bob` (the one that connects the lines of the triangle) makes on each line, and then put the middle line turtles (`l1`, `l2`, `l3`) tilt in that angle. It would then make it go right and left and draw the line. I'm sorry if this is unclear, but I can't really think of another way to explain it. This is my code:

```
import turtle

tur = turtle.Turtle() #draws the dots
bob = turtle.Turtle() #connects the dots
l1 = turtle.Turtle() #middle point of line 1
l2 = turtle.Turtle() #middle point of line 2
l3 = turtle.Turtle() #middle point of line 3
mid = turtle.Turtle() #point where the lines cross, haven't used this one yet
screen = turtle.Screen()
screen.tracer(0,0)

screen.setup(800,800)

tur.ht()
tur.up()
tur.speed(0)
bob.ht()
bob.up()
bob.speed(0)
screen.update()

l1.up()
l2.up()
l3.up()
mid.up()
mid.ht()

dots = 1

def lines():
    line()
    l1.goto(line_1_mid_cords) #go to middle of lines
    l1.dot()
    l2.goto(line_2_mid_cords)
    l2.dot()
    l3.goto(line_3_mid_cords)
    l3.dot()

def line():
    global line_1_mid_cords, line_2_mid_cords, line_3_mid_cords
    line_1_mid_cords = (( bob_x1 + bob_x2 ) /2, ( bob_y1 + bob_y2 ) /2) #get middle coordinates
    
    line_2_mid_cords = (( bob_x2 + bob_x3 ) /2, ( bob_y2 + bob_y3 ) /2)
    
    line_3_mid_cords = (( bob_x1 + bob_x3 ) /2, ( bob_y1 + bob_y3 ) /2)
    

def dotOnClick(x,y):
    global dots, bob_x1, bob_y1, bob_x2, bob_y2, bob_x3, bob_y3
    
    if dots == 1:
        if x >= -800 and x <= 800 and y >= -800 and y <= 800: #click on screen
            tur.goto(x,y) #go to that point
            bob.goto(tur.pos())#bob goes there too
            bob_x1 = bob.xcor() #saves bobs coordinates
            bob_y1 = bob.ycor()
            tur.dot()
            bob.down()
            screen.update()
            dots = 2 
                
    elif dots == 2:
        if x >= -800 and x <= 800 and y >= -800 and y <= 800: #when second dot is clicked
            tur.goto(x,y) #both tur and bob to to that point and they get connected
            bob.goto(tur.pos())
            bob_x2 = bob.xcor()
            bob_y2 = bob.ycor()
            tur.dot() #draws second dot
            bob.down()
            screen.update()
            dots = 3
    
    elif dots == 3:
        if x >= -800 and x <= 800 and y >= -800 and y <= 800: #same for 3rd point on screen
            tur.goto(x,y)
            bob.goto(tur.pos())
            bob_x3 = bob.xcor()
            bob_y3 = bob.ycor()
            tur.dot()
            bob.down()
            bob.goto(bob_x1,bob_y1) #bob goes to first dot and completes the triangle
            lines() #makes the turtles l1, l2, l3 go to the middle points of the triangle lines
            screen.update()
            dots = 4
       
    elif dots == 4:
        if x >= -800 and x <= 800 and y >= -800 and y <= 800: #resets when you click again
            tur.clear()
            bob.clear()
            screen.update()
            tur.reset()
            bob.reset()
            tur.ht()
            tur.up()
            tur.speed(0)
            bob.ht()
            bob.up()
            bob.speed(0)
            screen.update()
            dots = 1

        
turtle.onscreenclick(dotOnClick,1,True)
```

If I need to explain more about what I exactly mean, please say so!

Comment: Is your goal to save the angles of the first triangle to variables?

Comment: Yes, when bob is connecting the dots, he draws the lines in certain angles/degrees. I want to use these to put the l1, l2 and l3 turtles in these angles/degrees as well. So yeah, is it possible to save them to a variable?

Comment: Or, I basically want to align l1, l2 and l3 with the lines of the triangles. Yes align is the right word sorry. I thought maybe I could do it this way

Comment: Have you tried `.towards(x,y)` to see at what angle a point is relative to a turtles `.heading()`? Maybe look into that or you could calculate the angles yourself with the pairs of coordinates and set the headings for `l1`, `l2` and `l3`. 
As a last trick you could face each turtle to the next point, say `l1.towards(bob_x3, bob_y3)` and then `l1.rotate(somenumber)` to tilt in whichever direction you want

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After putting your mid-point turtles in their spot, you can aim them towards the next point on the triangle.

```py
def lines():
    line()
    l1.goto(line_1_mid_cords) #go to middle of lines
    l1.setheading(l1.towards(bob_x2, bob_y2))
    l1.dot()
    l2.goto(line_2_mid_cords)
    l2.setheading(l2.towards(bob_x3, bob_y3))
    l2.dot()
    l3.goto(line_3_mid_cords)
    l3.setheading(l3.towards(bob_x1, bob_y1))
    l3.dot()
```